# The difference between writing p3m1 and p31m

Tags: x-ray-crystallography

I've come across the two plane group symbols p3m1 and p31m. I've also figured out the differences between the two. But my question is in general about the notation. What's the difference between the notations p3m1 and p31m? How does writing "1" after/before the "m" changes things? I'd appreciate it if someone could give an answer with drawings or references to websites that have explanations in general about the naming style.

Comment: Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group) was not clear enough?

Comment: Hi Jon, "The next two symbols indicate symmetries relative to one translation axis of the pattern, referred to as the "main" one; if there is a mirror perpendicular to a translation axis we choose that axis as the main one (or if there are two, one of them). The symbols are either m, g, or 1, for mirror, glide reflection, or none. The axis of the mirror or glide reflection is perpendicular to the main axis for the first letter, and either parallel or tilted 180°/n (when n > 2) for the second letter. " This is the part of wikipedia that was unclear. Could you explain this wrt p3m1 and p31m ?